# EJB TransactionRequiredException in GlassFish 2.1

Tags: java, exception, transactions, ejb

In my `Stateful` bean, I have the following lines:

```
@Stateful(mappedName = "ejb/RegistrationBean")
@StatefulTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 30)
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class RegistrationStateful implements RegistrationStatefulRemote {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    private List<Event> reservedSessions = new ArrayList<Event>();
    private boolean madePayment = false;

    ...
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    private void cancelReservation() {
        if (reservedSessions.size() != 0) {
            Teacher theTeacher;
            for (Event session : reservedSessions) {
                if ((theTeacher = session.teacher) == null) theTeacher = bestTeacher.teacher;
                theTeacher = em.merge(theTeacher) //The exception is thrown here

                //Make changes to theTeacher

                em.flush(); //The exception is also thrown here
            }

            //Clear the reservedSessions list
            reservedSessions.clear();
        }
    }

    @Remove
    public void endRegistration() {}

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        //Cancel outstanding reservations if payment has not been made
        if (!madePayment) cancelReservation(); 
    }
}
```

The line `em.merge(someEntity)` throws the `TransactionRequiredException`. Could someone please tell me why it happens? I thought with `TransactionAttribute.REQUIRED`, a transaction will AUTOMATICALLY be created if there isn't an active one. I tried to use `em.joinTransaction()` but it throws the same `Exception`. I'm a beginner at this transaction thing. I'd be very grateful if someone could explain this to me.

**UPDATE:** I'd like to add a bit more information

The `Stateful` bean actually also has the following function:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
private void reserveSession(List<Event> sessions) throws ReservationException {
    //Reserve the sessions
    Teacher theTeacher;

    for (Event session : sessions) {
        if ((theTeacher = session.teacher) == null) theTeacher = bestTeacher.teacher;
        theTeacher = em.merge(theTeacher);

        //Make changes to theTeacher            

        em.flush();
    }   
}
```

The flow is as following: the user tells me his free time and I reserve some seats for him. After that, I show him his reserved seats and he can choose to make payment or cancel the reservations.

The `reserved()` function worked perfectly as expected but the `cancelReservation()` did not.

**UPDATE 2:** I have fixed the problem last night by commenting out the lines "@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)", "em.merge(theTeacher)" and "em.flush()" in the "cancelReservation()" function. The result is perfect. Would it be safe if I cut off those lines? I was afraid I would get "detached entity" exception when I used "em.merge()" in the first place.

Comment: Can you show us your Spring configuration xml?  The @Transaction will do this as long as it's setup correctly

Comment: Ouch. I think I missed something here. I have never configured any Spring XML file.

Comment: Yes - that would be the cause then.  If you want to use the annotations then you need a dependency injection container (Spring being the most popular) to handle this part of your application.  If you've never set one up it may be a little frustrating at first but you'll love what it has to offer once you get rolling!

Comment: Are you even using Spring?  I don't see it mentioned in your post, just some of the comments.

Comment: Indeed, REQUIRED starts a new transaction if there isn't already one active. Note that it's also the default, so specifying it is redundant. Anyway, it should work like this and as your identical `reserve()` method indicates it actually does. How do you get a hold of your bean and could you should the beginning of your class definition?

Comment: How is your database configured?  The default persistence provider is TopLink essentials, and the default DB is Java DB (Derby).  See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4336/6nfqd2b88/index.html for more info.

Comment: How do you run your application ? What application server are you using ?

Comment: @ JamesBoyZ: To clarify, if you are not using Spring, you can ignore @Michael's comments about Spring. They are completely irrelevant. You are using standard J2EE transaction management, which is entirely independent of Spring.

Comment: We'd very much like to see more code of the bean - full code of the `reserve` and `cancelReservations` methods, in particular - and the code from which the failing call is made.

Comment: -Arjan: I have added the beginning of my Stateful bean class.
-Costi: I am using GlassFish 2.1.1
-Tom Anderson: I will edit my post soon =). 
-g051051: Yes, I am using TopLink essential. However, I have just changed to use MySQL instead of JavaDB (Derby).

Comment: Please ignore my answer and I will delete it.  I jumped to conclusions. I've been so jaded by the early EJB implementations and their lack of test-ability i tend to dismiss them completely.

Comment: @JamesBoyZ: Regarding your latest comment, if there's no transaction, and no flush, why would the changes ever be written to the database? This doesn't strike me as a solution at all!

Comment: @JamesBoyZ: One other thing. The merge needs to be `theTeacher = em.merge(theTeacher);`, because the EntityManager may return a different object instance if it merges. If you keep the merge, that is.

Comment: @Tom: as Arjan wrote above, REQUIRED is default so there will always be transaction. Besides, we only need to call "em.flush()" if we want to manually flush if needed at some point. Otherwise, at the end of the method call, the JPA provider will automatically update the database at flush or commit time. I find this blog [link](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/) pretty useful on this matter. Check out the last part! =)

Comment: @James: Right, but my fear, as i say in my answer, is that the invocation of `cancelReservations` is not being treated as a business method, so it doesn't get a transaction. Have you verified that the changes are actually being written to the database? After all, if it works without the lines you deleted, it should work exactly the same with them.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, I have already confirmed the changes in the database. In other words, it worked without those lines while it didn't when those lines are still there. I'm not sure why =).

Comment: Okay, then i'm baffled too. Good news, though!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that springs to mind (if you'll excuse the pun) is that if you're calling `cancelReservation()` from another method inside the bean, then i'm not sure the transaction annotation will be observed. The annotation ultimately works by summoning an interceptor, and i believe interceptors are only applied to calls between different classes (this is something i should really check).

So, if you have a non-transactional method on the bean which calls a transactional method, then a transaction won't be started when the transactional method is called.

I could be completely wrong about this. I'll go and have a bit of a read of the spec and get back to you.

EDIT: I had a read of the spec, and it reminded me what a disaster zone the J2EE specs are. Horrific. However, the section on transactions does seem to imply that the transaction attributes only apply to calls made to an EJB's business interface. I believe calls from one method to another inside a bean are not considered to go through the business interface, even when the method being called is part of that interface. Therefore, you wouldn't expect them to attract transactions.

Something you could try would be to route them through the interface; there is no nice way of doing this, but you should be able to inject a business-interface self-reference like this:

```
public class RegistrationStateful implements RegistrationStatefulRemote {
    @EJB
    private RegistrationStatefulRemote self;
```

You can then change your @PreDestroy method to look like this:

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    self.cancelReservation();
}
```

And i believe that should count as a normal business interface call, with transactions and so on.

I have never actually tried this, so this could be complete rubbish. If you try it, let me know how it works out!

Comment: Hmm. This is interesting! Actually, my Stateful bean has a non-transactional @PreDestroy function which would call the "cancelReservation()" function. I'm not sure if it caused the issue.

Comment: if we use "@EJB", would it inject another instance of Stateful bean instead of using the current one?

Comment: did you see my question above? =)

Comment: I was under the impression that it would inject a reference to itself. Having given it a try, it seems that's not the case, and it injects a reference to a new bean, as you say. Which also gets injected with a reference to a new bean, and so on, which causes a stack overflow. I guess you need to do something with a qualifier to make this do the desired thing - no idea how.

Comment: +1 for "what a disaster zone the J2EE specs are. Horrific. ". I've printed out JSR-318 (EJB 3.1), read about the sessions, and decided that Spring is a lot easier. So I read Spring in Action instead. But that's just for my personal time. My current work, we use EJBs

Comment: It's sad, because the environment the specs describe is actually not at all bad, in fact it's rather good. It's just that it's absurdly hard to discover what it is by reading the specs!